# Android edittext input orientation

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is there any way that can change the Android Edittext input orientation? Which is top to bottom and right to left, Just like the images below:

i.stack.imgur.com/6T6ht.jpg

The style is similar to Japanese and Chinese letter

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4u9v.jpg

Thanks!

---

Update

Sorry for my unclear expression, although the input orientation is correct, the 
text direction is rotated which is unwanted. For the better expression, I updated 
the image below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz6RB.jpg

Big Thanks!!!!

Comment: is that solved or??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Try with Custom VerticalEditText like below

Class - VerticalEditText.java

```
package com.cj.myapplication.croper;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;

/**
 * Created by CHETAN JOSHI on 2/3/2017.
 */

public class VerticalEditText extends EditText {
    private Rect bounds = new Rect();
    private TextPaint textPaint;
    private int color;

    public VerticalEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public VerticalEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        color = getCurrentTextColor();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        textPaint = getPaint();
        textPaint.getTextBounds(getText().toString(), 0, getText().length(), bounds);
        setMeasuredDimension((int) (bounds.height() + textPaint.descent()), bounds.width());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        textPaint.setColor(color);
        canvas.rotate(-90, bounds.width(), 0);
        canvas.drawText(getText().toString(), 0, -bounds.width() + bounds.height(), textPaint);
    }
}
```

Add in XML like below:

```
 <com.cj.myapplication.croper.VerticalEditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="bbfrbgbrfgbirfbgubui"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your editText for right to left

```
android:textDirection="rtl"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add rotation attribute in EditText

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:rotation="270"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,then create other edittexts. it worked for me

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:rotation="270"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```